# Can't center social media icons in the footer

Tags: html, css

I've been stuck on a problem for over 2 days and I need to ask for help. On Desktop browsers the icons are suppose to left align and in mobile browsers they are are suppose to center align.

Here is the site so far.

[Inspect Site Here](http://mazurick.com/testo/index.html)

I've created a website where the layout is comprised of stacked sections where height and width values of each section are defined using VH percentages to get a specific layout.

This is an example of how a section is defined in the CSS.

```
.content3 {
height: 100vh;
width: 100%;
display: table;
background: #FFFFFF url('../img/chair.png') no-repeat center center;
background-size: 60%;
}
```

Here is how I defined the footer's CSS.

```
.footer {
height: 40vh;
width: 100%;
background: #312D3B;
}
```

Here is the HTML for the .footer

```
<section class="footer">
<div class="Social">
    <img class="icons" src="img/dribbble.svg">
    <img class="icons2" src="img/twitter.svg">
    <img class="icons3" src="img/instagram.svg">
</div>
```

Here is the CSS for the .Social class

```
.Social {
height: 100%;
float: left;
position: relative;
}
```

Here is the CSS for the .icons class

```
.icons {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding-left: 3.5em;
    }
```

Here is the CSS for the .icons2 class

```
    .icons2 {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 4.5em;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding-left: 3.5em;
    }
```

Here is the css for the icons3 class

```
.icons3 {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 9em;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding-left: 3.5em;
    }
```

Please help. This is my first question ever on this site.

Comment: You should use media query for that. https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use flexbox to help you with this issue, just replace style.css code with this one

CSS:

```
/* -------------------------------- 

Primary style

-------------------------------- */
*, *::after, *::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #1C1D21;
}

/* -------------------------------- 

Final project

-------------------------------- */

main {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0 0 50px #000;
    transition: transform .5s;
}

.nav-open main {
    transform: scale(.8);
}

.intro {
    height: 90vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    background: #FCC732 url('../img/WatchByMaz2.png') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 90%;
}

.content {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    background: #FFFFFF url('../img/OculusConsumerByMaz.png') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 90%;
}

.content2 {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    background: #FCC732 url('../img/speedingAppByMaz.png') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 90%;
}

.content3 {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    background: #FFFFFF url('../img/chair.png') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 60%;
}

.footer {
    height: 40vh;
    width: 100%;
    background: #312D3B;

}

.main-header {
    position: relavtive;
    background: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;

}

section .center {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 4em;
}

.btn {
  -webkit-border-radius: 28;
  -moz-border-radius: 28;
  border-radius: 28px;
  font-family: 'lulo_cleanone' , Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #312D3B;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  border: solid #312D3B 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.logo {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 43px;
    left: 44px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'lulo_cleanone_bold' , Arial, sans-serif;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 90px;
    color: #312D3B;
}

.nav-trigger {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 4;
    top: 40px;
    right: 46px;
    height: 44px;
    width: 44px;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: transparent;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-indent: 100%;
}

.nav-trigger span,
.nav-trigger span::before,
.nav-trigger span::after {
    position: absolute;
    height: 4px;
    width: 40px;
    background: #000000;
}

.nav-trigger span {
    width: 29px;
}

.nav-trigger span {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transition: background .3s;
}

.nav-trigger span::before,
.nav-trigger span::after {
    content: '';
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: background .3s, transform .3s;
}

.nav-trigger span::before {
    transform: translateY(-12px);
}

.nav-trigger span::after {
    transform: translateY(12px);
}

.nav-trigger:hover span, 
.nav-trigger:hover span::before,
.nav-trigger:hover span::after {
    background: #000000;
}

.nav-open .nav-trigger span {
    background: transparent;
}

.nav-open .nav-trigger span::before,
.nav-open .nav-trigger span::after {
    background: #FFFFFF;
}

.nav-open .nav-trigger span::before {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.nav-open .nav-trigger span::after {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #1C1D21;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: opacity .5s, visibility .5s;
}

.nav-open .overlay {
    opacity: .6;
    visibility: visible;

}

.nav-container {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 3;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 460px;
    padding: 2em 3.5em;
    background: #312D3B;
    overflow: hidden;
    transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform .5s cubic-bezier(.07,.23,.34,1);
}

.nav-open .nav-container {
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.nav-container h2 {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: 'lulo_cleanone' , Arial, sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #AAAAAA;
    margin: 2.3em 0;
}

.nav {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}

.nav a {
    display: block;
    padding: .4em 0;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'lulo_cleanone' , Arial, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    transform: translateZ(0);
}

.nav-open .nav a {
    animation: slide-in .4s .2s backwards;
}

.nav-open .nav li:nth-of-type(2) a {
    animation-delay: .3s;
}

.nav-open .nav li:nth-of-type(3) a {
    animation-delay: .4s;
}

.nav-open .nav li:nth-of-type(4) a {
    animation-delay: .5s;
}

.nav-open .nav li:nth-of-type(5) a {
    animation-delay: .6s;
}

@keyframes slide-in {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(80px);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}


.Social {

    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto;


}

.icons {


}

.icons2 {

        padding-left: 5.5em;
}

.icons3 {

        padding-left: 6em;
}





.portfolio_nav {
    height: 20vh;
    width: 100%;
    background: #312D3B;
}

.left_tab {
    width: 49%;
    height:100%;
    background: #312D3B;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.right_tab {
    width: 49%;
    height:100%;
    background: #FFC600;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
}

.arrow {
    max-height: 100%;  
    max-width: 100%; 
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;  
    top: 0;  
    bottom: 0;  
    left: 0;  
    right: 0;  
    margin: auto;
}

.middle2 {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'lulo_cleanone_bold';
    src: url('../yellow_design_studio_-_lulo_clean_one_bold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../yellow_design_studio_-_lulo_clean_one_bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../yellow_design_studio_-_lulo_clean_one_bold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../yellow_design_studio_-_lulo_clean_one_bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../yellow_design_studio_-_lulo_clean_one_bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../yellow_design_studio_-_lulo_clean_one_bold-webfont.svg#lulo_cleanone_bold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}




@font-face {
    font-family: 'lulo_cleanone';
    src: url('../yellow_design_studio_-_lulo_clean_one-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../yellow_design_studio_-_lulo_clean_one-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../yellow_design_studio_-_lulo_clean_one-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../yellow_design_studio_-_lulo_clean_one-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../yellow_design_studio_-_lulo_clean_one-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../yellow_design_studio_-_lulo_clean_one-webfont.svg#lulo_cleanone') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}


/* -------------------------------- 

Desktop Media Queries

-------------------------------- */

@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {

.intro {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    background: #FCC732 url('../img/WatchByMaz2.png') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 60%;
}


.content {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    background: #F6F3F3 url('../img/OculusConsumerByMaz.png') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 60%;
}


.content2 {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    background: #FCC732 url('../img/speedingAppByMaz.png') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 60%;
}

.content3 {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    background: #FFFFFF url('../img/chair.png') center no-repeat;
    background-size: 30%;
}

.Social {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    height: 100%;
    width: 30%;
    margin: 0 auto;

}

.icons {


}

.icons2 {

        padding-left: 3.5em;
}

.icons3 {

        padding-left: 3.5em;
}
```

Comment: This was the most effective solution. It worked perfectly. I just increased the em sizes because when I was testing in the iPhone Safari simulator the buttons were tiny. I genuinely appreciate your help. This site is fantastic.

Comment: Glad it worked :) Try to learn more Flexbox and you will be amazed of how easily you can create super websites.[Tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Also don't add any padding to the first icon as it will push everything to the right.

Comment: btw, don't forget to mark this answer as correct, just click the  up arrow in my answer please

Comment: Hey, I think I upvoted it right. Let me know. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

[image: mobile view]

Here's a way to do it. Remove all `absolute` positions of `.icon, .icon2`and`.icon3`

Add this code on desktop :

```
.Social {
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 40vh;
}
```

And this code on mobile with a media query for example :

```
@media (max-width: 640px) {
  .Social {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

Change `padding-left` values for mobile like this :

```
.icons { padding-left: 1em; }
.icons2 { padding-left: 1em; }
.icons3 { padding-left: 1em; }
```

And keep `padding-left` values for desktop like this for example :

```
.icons { padding-left: 3.5em; }
.icons2 { padding-left: 3.5em; }
.icons3 { padding-left: 3.5em; }
```

I've tested it, it should works.